# Creating X and Y axis for a game

Tags: math, lua, counting

Recently I was thinking about creating my own axis x/y, especially 'x', but in that game in which I want to create it, there are no values below 0, because pointX = 0 is on left screen border.

I want to create function which will smoothly count all values depends on our game resolution X.

For example:

parameters: min value, max value, screenX, cursorPosition

```
if(cursorPosition == screenWidth/2) then
  return 0
end
```

When cursor position is below screenWidth/2, function will smoothly count value between -0 and min value (min value will be, when cursor position = 0)

and the same when cursor pos is above screenWidth/2, function will smoothly count value between 0 and max value (max value will be when cursor position = our screenX)

Can anyone explain to me, how can I reach an effect like that? :)

Regards

Comment: You will need some kind of two-dimensional lua game engine. Try LÖVE.

Comment: Actually i am writing that code to game called Multi Theft Auto San Andreas, i've already got variables like screenX or cursor position but i don't know how to create correct pattern to count that values ;/

Comment: Alright, i've made it, thanks for help

Comment: now you know why you shouldn't have slept in maths class...

Answer (score 0):

use linear interpolation to change the dynamic range. Let assume your view has `xs,ys` resolution and point `(0,0)` is top left corner. so the dynamic range per each axis is:

```cpp
x = <0,xs-1>
y = <0,ys-1>
```

and you want to change it to:

```cpp
x' = <minx,maxx>
y' = <miny,maxy>
```

So do this:

```cpp
x' = minx + x*(maxx-minx)/(xs-1)
y' = miny + y*(maxy-miny)/(ys-1)
```

and if you need to go back for any reason:

```cpp
x = (x'-minx)*(xs-1)/(maxx-minx)
y = (y'-miny)*(ys-1)/(maxy-miny)
```

where `(minx,miny)` is top left corner and `(maxx,maxy)` is bottom right corner. If you want to change also the sign of any axis then you can as `minx<maxx` is not required for this so just swap the initial values so `minx>maxx`.

Not coding in **lua** but If your values are floating then beware integer rounding while mixing integers and floats together.